# Netbeans "Run File" doesn't work on HTML or JSP (Java Web Application)

Tags: java, html, netbeans, web-applications

I recently downloaded and installed Netbeans 11, JDK 13 and Apache Tomcat 9 (from the official sites). Soon I noticed that when you press "Run File" or Shift+F6 on a html file in a java web application, it does absolutely nothing. No response, no output, nothing. JSP files won't run as well. Unexplicably, if you select the project and press "Run" or the "Run Project" button (F6), the index.html file shows in the browser as expected, but no other pages (obviously).

So far, I've tried the following things:

- Uninstalling, deleting the cache and reinstalling in different locations (C: , D: , etc.).
- Creating multiple web applications with different names in different locations.
- Tried with different versions (Netbeans 10 and JDK 12). Same problem.
- If you create a Java Application, the "Run File" option does work on Java Main Classes. Apparently, the problem is exclusive to WEB applications.

Answer (score 9):

On each app you make: Go to the application setting by right click - properties. Under Build uncheck compile on save.

Comment: I read a dozen discussions on how to tame it and nothing came of it. One short sentence was enough here and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the above solution worked for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question, this would be more appropriate as a comment. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).